# Android custom radiobutton

Tags: android, radio-button

I want to make custom radio button.I have created a drawable for normal(radio_normal) state.But I find it difficult to create a shape for checked state(radio_pressed).I have tried creating my desired way.But didn't work out well.I don't know if I have done it the right way.For checked state the shape should look like this.The outer border and the inner circle must be white in color.Can anybody help me with that?

radio_normal:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:useLevel="false">
    <solid
        android:color="#2196f3"></solid>

</shape>
```

radio_pressed:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
    <shape android:shape="oval"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <solid
            android:color="@android:color/transparent">
        </solid>
        <size
             android:height="60dp"
            android:width="60dp">
       </size>
      <stroke
          android:color="#ffffff"
          android:width="1dp"
          >
    </stroke>
    </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid
                    android:color="#ffffff">
                </solid>
            </shape>
            <size
                android:height="30dp"
                android:width="30dp">
    </size>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

radio_bg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_checked="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/radio_pressed"
    >
</item>
    <item
        android:state_checked="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/radio_normal"
        >
    </item>
</selector>
```

activity_main:

```
<RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:button="@drawable/radio_bg"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is about as close as I can get you, hope it works on your side and that it helps :)

radio_normal:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:useLevel="false">
    <solid android:color="#2196f3" />
    <size
        android:width="25dp"
        android:height="25dp" />
</shape>
```

radio_pressed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:padding="3dp">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <size
                android:width="25dp"
                android:height="25dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="7dp"
        android:left="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        android:top="7dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="oval"
            android:useLevel="false">

            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

radio_bg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/radio_pressed"
        >
    </item>
    <item
        android:state_checked="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/radio_normal"
        >
    </item>
</selector>
```

activity_main:

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:button="@drawable/radio_bg"/>
```

Let me know if this worked for you :)

Comment: But the problem is I cannot set a specific dimension for radio button.Works only if it is match_parent or wrap_content.Specifying a dimension gives it an irregular shape.

Answer (score 0):

Is this maybe what you were looking for ?

radio_pressed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <size
                android:width="10dp"
                android:height="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="3dp"
        android:left="3dp"
        android:right="3dp"
        android:top="3dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="oval"
            android:useLevel="false">

            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Reaction to comment:**

[image: You should get this when you change bottom, top, left and right to 50 dp]

The code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <size
                android:width="150dp"
                android:height="150dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="50dp"
        android:left="50dp"
        android:right="50dp"
        android:top="50dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="oval"
            android:useLevel="false">

            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Note:** The only changes made was in the sizes to accomodate your imageview of 150dp X 150dp. When using it for your radio button I highly reccomend using the 10x10dp sizes

Comment: I set it as background of imageview to see if it is visible, I could see only white circular background at dimension 150dp

Comment: Note that 
        android:bottom="3dp"
        android:left="3dp"
        android:right="3dp"
        android:top="3dp

wont resize with the view. Change those values to something like 50 or 60dp (since your dimensions are 150x150dp). You should see it then. If you use the code provided by me at the 10x10dp you should see a nice white checked radio button

Comment: I changed top bottom and other dimensions to 50dp as you said.The radio button is not visible

Comment: When I set it to 50dp in radio_pressed I could see only white ring now the inner circle is gone

Comment: In the preview it will dissapear. But when you run it you should see it in your imageView

Comment: I reccomend keeping the sizes the same as the ones I gave in the above example since a radio button would be about 10dp and not 150

Comment: I set the radio button dimen to 10dp and run the app.The radio button became invisible.

Comment: I have posted some other details.I have only set it to ImageView just to see if it(radio_pressed) becomes visible..I need it for radio_button.Please see my edited question